# How to retain simple TFS check-in comment formatting when entered in VS2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to retain simple formatting like newlines in a TFS check-in comment entered in VS2015 but viewed using the web interface?

For example, in VS2015 I enter:

```
Fixed yadda, yadda, yadda:
- added validation to check for X
- added confirmation dialog to ask User if the want to continue despite X
- etc
```

But in the TFS web interface, it displays as:

```
Fixed yadda, yadda, yadda: - added validation to check for X - added confirmation dialog to ask User if the want to continue despite X - etc
```

And the longer the comment, the bigger the unbroken blob of text in the web interface.

If you enter the same formatted comment in the web interface instead of VS, it retains the formatting.

I know it has to do with HTML vs text and the \n in the text provided by VS isn't converted to an HTML linebreak(or whatever it uses) in the web interface, but is there anything that can be done?

Thanks.

**Edit**
I'm entering this comment into the field on the Pending Changes window, not the full page Task window.
Also, using TFS 2013.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: We're using TFS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with my TFS2015.3 + VS2015.3, the format of check-in comment is the same as in VS. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

---

Adding a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you enter that comment in the "Comment" field of the Pending Changes window or in the "full" TFS tab/window of the work item?  I'm using the Pending Changes window(will update question)

Comment: I entered the comment in the "Comment" field of the Pending Changes window. I just tested in TFS2013.5, the format of check-in comment is also the same as in VS. You may check your TFS edition and upgrade to the latest one.

Comment: We're running TFS version 12.0.31101.0 (Tfs2013.Update4).  I will try again after I can manage to get it updated, but I don't know when that will be...so what's the protocol here?  I believe you but cannot yet confirm it.  Should I accept the answer or leave it open until I can test it myself(who knows when that will be)?

Comment: Sorry...one other thing: what does your comment look like in the actual individual Work Item screen, not the Code->Changesets, but Work->Task XYZ?